# I've been trying to insert a specific data to my database

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle12c

I have been trying to insert a data into my database, but it seems am missing a comma , and i have tried to figure out where , but i cant seems to find the issue, any help would be appreciated... newbie here..
thanks

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES
( FIRST_NAME ,
LAST_NAME , 
EMAIL , 
PHONE_NUMBER , 
HIRE_DATE , 
JOB_ID , 
Salary , 
COMMISSION_PCT , 
MANAGER_ID , 
DEPARTMENT_ID )


VALUES  ( 

'Jackson' ,
'Kayode' ,
'amima@gmail@gmail.com',
216.313.9890 , 
12-12-18 , 
'AD_PRES' ,
10500 , 
0.10 , 
100 , 
90 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need single quotes around date constants and strings.  I would recommend using the `date` keyword:

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES (FIRST_NAME , LAST_NAME , EMAIL , PHONE_NUMBER , HIRE_DATE , JOB_ID , Salary , COMMISSION_PCT , MANAGER_ID , DEPARTMENT_ID)
    VALUES ('Jackson', 'Kayode', 'amima@gmail@gmail.com', '216.313.9890',
            date '2018-12-12', 'AD_PRES', 10500, 0.10, 100, 90
          );
```

Comment: Thanks boss,i got this report when i tried to run the statement :-
SQL Error: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("HR"."EMPLOYEES"."EMPLOYEE_ID")
01400. 00000 -  "cannot insert NULL into (%s)"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to insert NULL into previously listed objects.
*Action:   These objects cannot accept NULL values.

Comment: OK, so - what's the problem? Do you not understand what Oracle has told you? You have to provide value for EMPLOYEE_ID as that column is set to be NOT NULL.